# Angular2 Matrix Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this link that work perfect.

```
<li class="page-item" routerLinkActive="active"><a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/admin/users']" [queryParams]="{page: 1}">1</a></li>
```

And generate a url like domain.com/admin/users?page=1

Now I need from code to change the url and make this.

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/users', {page: 1}]);
```

But this generate domain.com/admin/users;page=1

Why? The second method dosn't not recognise the page as param

Comment: Just FYI, the second method defines optional parameters, which are read different from query parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it.

This is different

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/users', {queryParams:{page:1}}]);
```

from that

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/users'], {queryParams:{page:1}});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to set like this below:

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/users'], { queryParams: { page: 1} });
```